# How to refer al subview hierarchy in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiview

Hello I'm trying to apply some styles to `IBOutlets` from `Swift 3` code. But when I'm trying to refer the `IBOutlet` from my code, only works if I add the immediatelly superior `UIView` as `IBOutlet`.

For example (adding font style to all label elements inside View):

Declaration

```
@IBOutlet var exampleView: UIView!
```

Inside `ViewDidLoad() func`

```
for case let label as UILabel in exampleView.subviews {
            label.font = UIFont(name: "myfont-name", size: 13.0)
}
```

In this case the `label` is a immediate child of the `exampleView` and this works fine. But I want to do more general code for dynamic font type change in my app.

When I try to refer to `self.view.subviews` for loop all the labels no mather hierarchy depth the code don't work.

Example:

```
for case let label as UILabel in self.view.subviews {
            label.font = UIFont(name: "myfont-name", size: 13.0)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use recursion for this

```
func setFontToSubviews(view:UIView, font: UIFont) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
             label.font = font
        }
        setFontToSubviews(view:subview, font:font)
    }
}
```

and invoke this method with required view and font.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very useful